How to package a component library with multiple modules?
I've written a large component library with various top-level folders like api, components, utils etc. During initial development I used exports in package.json to define convenient entry locations that my code could be imported from, like <package>/utils. But I had these exports pointing to the /src folder, not to the /dist folder produced by webpack.
Now I am trying to figure out how to properly package my library - and do so in a manner that supports my ability to use sub-paths to avoid otherwise very tedious code to pull out nested type definitions.
I moved away from exports (in combination with distinct entry point definitions in webpack) as I got into issues with react and other things getting multiple, distinct instances when importing. My current approach is to instead just use the one bundled file /dist/main.js.
This partially works. This allows me to import from sub-paths via the dist folder like so: import {...} from '<package>/dist/sub/path'.
This will successfully import the type information from my component library for re-use in other projects. However, when I actually go to compile a project that uses the library, I get errors like this one:
ERROR in ./src/redux/store.tsx 17:14-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '<package>/dist/redux' in '/home/user/repos/<some-project>/src/redux'
 @ ./src/app.tsx 11:14-38
 @ ./src/index.tsx 34:28-44 54:15-39

While the /dist folder maintains the same folder structure as /src, and while it contains all of the type definition files (*.d.ts), the only javascript file is the one bundled by webpack: /dist/main.js
I'm guessing that the reason my compilation attempts are failing is because it is looking for a corresponding index.js file under the specified sub-path and isn't finding it - resulting in the error.
How I can package this library in such a way as to properly support sub-paths for imports?

This will be a whole lot easier if your package is just an ESM one. What purpose is webpack at the library level serving? Why bundle?

exports is the answer here. But that doesn't have to point to a webpacked bundle at all. It can just point to the relevant JS as produced from tsc. No bundling is really necessary.

@adsy primarily using it because that’s what all our other projects use. But perhaps, as you say, it is the wrong tool for the job. I will try using just tsc as you recommend!

@adsy Just using tsc addresses the immediate problem - but then I'm left with others. In particularly: if I use tsc then it doesn't copy over my .scss files or the like - all the non-typescript assets.

@adsy Added some post-build scripts to copy the files over. The "last" problem is with image assets (.png). The import statements (like import image from "./Logo.png") no longer work. How would you recommend handling such assets without webpack for a re-usable library?

Typically, if it's a small thing, you'd embed that in some React component via SVG or data URIs. Alternatively, you could have it passed in as a prop and have the consumer import & pass it in themselves.

These sorts of constraints (no assumptions about consuming build system) are normal for ESM modules. But also considered good. You need it to be truly portable. Itd be a problem even if it was built with webpack as well unless they are inlined.

@adsy Thanks for all your help :) Finally got things importing correctly into my other projects out of this library. I've done a lot of react projects over the years - but this is actually the first time I've tried creating my own re-usable library haha. If you want to submit an answer I will accept it :)
